# Linux basicinformation about pci.ids

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

What is the pci.ids file? Where can I find it? What is the purpose of this file?

I'm new in Linux programming and stumbled over this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a repository of known ID's used in PCI devices: ID's of vendors, devices, subsystems and device classes. It is used in various programs to display full human-readable names instead of cryptic numeric codes.

The location of this file is at: `/usr/share/hwdata/pci.ids`

[Read more](http://pciids.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @ Nejc Thanks for the Answer. But what if I don't have `hwdata` in this folder ?

Comment: What distribution are you running?

You can also find it in `/var/lib/pciutils/pci.ids` or `/usr/share/pci.ids`. Maybe the best case is to find it in your file system with `find / -name pci.ids`.

Comment: What if there is no such a file on the pc? ( `find / -name pci.ids` no match ). I have just a blank 2.6.36 Kernel on my embedded board

Comment: From the description I assume, that you will not get any problems, you just won't be able to identify a device by its (human-readable) name.

Comment: I use debian and the location of the file is `/usr/share/misc/pci.ids`. For debian more info can be found at [HowToIdentifyADevice/PCI](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/PCI)